# strange mysql query issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have write two queries in nodejs in a function one is inserting data into db and other is getting count of chat messages.

It produces result like similar to below

> inserted id: 1 count: 1
>
> inserted id: 2 count 2
>
> inserted id: 3 count 3

and then issue comes

> inserted id: 4 count 3
>
> inserted id: 5 count 5

---

dont know why it count `3` display two times and skip count `4` and then sudden it show count `5`

does anyone help me to optimize my sql query with nodejs

I already tries async and await with my queries and i don't think it is the delay in running two queries.

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show some code that you have?

Comment: The most probable reasons are: (1) error during insertion (the row was not inserted) (2) not committed transaction.

Comment: @VadimSirbu  https://jsfiddle.net/sunilcodetribe/nh7mb8fg/

Comment: @Akina  - first reason is probably not because it increase the last insertedid every time in logs that means data inserted is success that is why it increase the count

Comment: That would be true for INNODB but not MyISAM

Comment: @Strawberry I also tried changinf innodb to myisam but it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to promisify connection query and await for the queries to run. Something similar to the code below:

```
function query (sql, binding) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, binding, (err, result, fields) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
};
```

Then you use `query` instead of `connection.query` with await

```
await query("INSERT ...");
await query("INSERT ...");
await query("INSERT ...");
...
const result = await query("SELECT ...");
```

Here is an article on this topic: https://medium.com/wenchin-rolls-around/example-of-using-transactions-with-async-await-via-mysql-connection-pool-9a37092f226f

Comment: unfortunetly this also fails , actually it skip one value once during sending messages and that too not frequently , it happens some times  may be once in  sending 30 messages. I think it is specific issue of db but dont know what.

Comment: issue resolved , its due to sockets. when I emit the final result it gets delay some time. and sometime works pefect. so I work on it and issue gets resolved